# join two table folder and image

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, union

```
       album
------------------
  aid  |  aname  |  
------------------
  1   | album1   | 
  2   | album2   | 
  3   | album3   | 
  4   | album4   | 
------------------

       image
---------------------------------------
  iid  |  title  |  albumid |  imgurl
---------------------------------------
  1   | img1     |   3      |  image3.jpg
  2   | img2     |   1      |  image1.jpg
  3   | img3     |   2      |  image4.jpg
  4   | img4     |   0      |  image5.jpg
---------------------------------------
```

I have two tables album and image. In image table albumid= 0 means that image does not belong to any folder. I need that imageurl with all folder names and count of images inside folder like below table in mysql.

**Example:**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
  id=aid+iid  |  name= aname +title | imgurl          | countimg
----------------------------------------------------------------
  1           | album1              |       null      |  1
  2           | album2              |       null      |  1
  3           | album3              |       null      |  1
  4           | album4              |       null      |  0
  4           | img4                |    image5.jpg   |  0
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can I have any help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in image, if there is no album, why not put null? plus please explain what you need, your example doesn't make any sense

Comment: I agree with No Idea For Name. Why is this 0 instead of null? With 0 in there you can not even use a database constraint on albums (i.e. a foreign key). Looks like a bad idea to me.

Comment: Ya I agree, but tables are created before, no rights to change.

Comment: Hi  No Idea For Name and  Thorsten Kettner, if I put null instead of 0 what will be the advantage? how can i use a database constraint on albums (i.e. a foreign key). because if I put null the data type can not be int(albumid) and the aid on album table is int type primary key. Then type mismatch error will be there. Please let me know if I am wrong. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.aid AS `id`, a.aname AS `name`, NULL AS imgurl, COUNT(i.iid) countimg 
FROM album a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN image i ON a.aid = i.albumid  
GROUP BY a.aid 
UNION 
SELECT a.iid AS `id`, i.title AS `name`, imgurl AS imgurl, 0 countimg 
FROM image i 
WHERE i.albumid = 0;
```

Comment: Hi Saharsh Shah, Thank you, it gives exactly what I am looking for. but can we avoid UNION? can we get it with only join query? Please suggest me.

Comment: @Ashim You're most welcome...As per me you have to use UNION in this query

Comment: @Ashim: UNION (this should better be UNION ALL by the way) is the best approach here, because you combine two different queries. You could solve this with a full outer join, however, if you really must avoid UNION for some reason.

Comment: Thank you Thorsten Kettner for you suggestion.